# IIS SSL Binding giving me warning saying "Binding hostname not equals to Certificate subject name"

Tags: ssl, iis, ssl-certificate, iis-10

I am trying to create a site and bind an SSL certificate via powershell on IIS 10.

```
   $SecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "Test" -AsPlainText -Force;
    Import-PfxCertificate -FilePath 'C:\certlocation\nt109tdash01.pfx' -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My -Password $SecurePassword; 
    Import-Module "WebAdministration"; 
    New-Item IIS:\Sites\Mysite -bindings @{protocol='https';bindingInformation='*:8080:nt109tdash01.idmz.abc';SslFlags=1} -PhysicalPath C:\site\; 
    New-Item -Path "IIS:\SslBindings\*!8080!nt109tdash01.idmz.abc" -Thumbprint 07D81714A4DE6ABBFEA71120B5FE9D7FEI83C375 -SslFlags 1;
```

When I am executing the commands, I am getting this below warning.

> WARNING: Binding host name 'nt109tdash01.idmz.abc' is not equals to
>   certificate subject name 'CN=nt109tdash01.idmz.abc, OU=Digital
>   Team,  O=My Company Corporation, L=Location, S=Some Location,
>   C=AU'. Client may not be able to connect to the site using HTTPS
>   protocol.

I was debugging and made this observation.
When I checked the system hostname, it is showing only **nt109tdash01** and there is no domain info.
I tried `wmic computersystem get domain`to get domain info, but it was blank as well.

Will that be causing the issues?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is just a warning. You can ignore it if your site does work.

Comment: Hi @LexLi Actually my site wont work. SSL connectivity is not established . I suspect it has something to do with this warning because I checked certificate and password and both are valid. And in the warning I didnt saw any difference between hostnames.

Comment: I have the same problem. New-Item fails, with WARNING, but the cert isn't added. I can manually go in through the IIS Manager and add the cert to the binding so there's nothing wrong with the binding or the cert - it's just New-Item has a problem.